# Reshape wide dataframe of unequal size to long format

Tags: r, reshape

I have started working on a sentiment analysis, but I have problem with transforming the lexicon into the required format

My data looks like something this:

| word | alternativeform1 | alternativeform2 | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abmachen | abgemacht | abmachst | 0.4 |
| Aktualisierung | Aktualisierungen | NA | 0.2 |

I need it to look like this

| word | value |
| --- | --- |
| abmachen | 0.4 |
| abgemacht | 0.4 |
| abmachst | 0.4 |
| Aktualisierung | 0.2 |
| Aktualisierungen | 0.2 |

Can you help me find the easy way to do this? Thank you very much :)

Comment: from tidyverse package, try the pivot_longer with the "value" column as the ID
df_long <- pivot_longer(data=df, cols=c(1:3), names_to="value", value_to="word")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-value, values_to = "word") %>% 
  drop_na(word) %>% 
  select(word, value)
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  word             value
  <chr>            <dbl>
1 abmachen           0.4
2 abgemacht          0.4
3 abmachst           0.4
4 Aktualisierung     0.2
5 Aktualisierungen   0.2
```